# Combining Nested Selections with SASS

Tags: css, sass

In CSS, I can make selections like this:

```
input[type="number"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="text"],
textarea,
.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

How do I nest my attribute selectors in SASS to achieve this output? The following SASS is causing my linter to scream (sass-lint, "Please check validity of the block").

```
input {
  &[type="number"] {}
  &[type="password"] {}
  &[type="text"] {}
},
textarea,
.button-base {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: When you nest 2 CSS selectors, the CSS code block is shared by the two selectors so even if you use SASS this is not a logic thing to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see what you are getting at, but it might be futile. I do not think that kind of compilation is going to happen.  This might be the closest you get:

```
textarea,
.button-base {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
input {
  &[type="number"],
  &[type="password"],
  &[type="text"] {
      @extend .button-base;
  }
}
```